# Functional Language Family of LISP and one Code Fragment?

Tags: list, functional-programming, lisp

In one Functional Language Family of LISP and with possibility of Defining Variables,

```
(defvar a '(1 2 3))
(defvar b (cons a (cdr a)))
(rplacd a '(5))
```

creates the `b` list as

```
((1 5) 2 3)
```

!! I'm surprized. How do these Code Fragments make this list? Could anyone explain these confusing commands ?!

Comment: That's not what I get when I try it. `a` is `(1 5)`, `b` is `((1 5) 2 3)`.

Comment: BTW, Lisp is not generally considered a functional language.

Comment: @Barmar you are right. I correct it.

Comment: Would you please add more detail for me? @Barmar

Comment: Draw the lists using box-and-pointer representations of all the conses, and you should see why it is.

Comment: No @Barmar my challenge is via defvar and cons and cdr command

Comment: No user4249446, you should follow the advice of @Barmar. Try reading Touretzky's book "A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation". -- and you forgot to mention the `rplacd`. That's the culprit. :)

Comment: thanks, any online compiler for LISP? @WillNess

Comment: @WillNess is it possible to say how get the output of each line?

Comment: Noun phrases which are not proper nouns such as "functional family" and "code fragment" do not require capitalization. Also, your code is not written in an entire "family". You are working in some specific dialect, one that looks like Common Lisp. The behavior of `(rplacd a ...)` is not defined in Common Lisp because `a` contains a literal object produced from a quoted list expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you do the first two `defvar` calls, you have the following variable assignments to conses.

```
A => +---+---+  +---+---+  +---+---+      
+--> | 1 | ---->| 2   ---->| 3 | ----> NIL
 \   +---+---+  +---+---+  +---+---+
  \            --^
   \          /   
    \        /                        
     \      /                        
      \    /      
B => +-\-+-|-+    
     | | | | |    
     +---+---+
```

In printed representation, this looks like:

```
A => (1 2 3)
B => ((1 2 3) 2 3)
```

When you perform the `rplacd`, it modifies the `cdr` of `a` to refer to a new `cons`. But the `cdr` of `b` still refers to the same `cons` as it did before this.

```
               +---+---+
             ->| 5 | ----> NIL
            /  +---+---+     
           /
A => +---+-|-+  +---+---+  +---+---+      
+--> | 1 | | |  | 2   ---->| 3 | ----> NIL
 \   +---+---+  +---+---+  +---+---+
  \            --^
   \          /   
    \        /                        
     \      /                        
      \    /      
B => +-\-+-|-+    
     | | | | |    
     +---+---+
```

In printed form, this looks like:

```
A => (1 5)
B => ((1 5) 2 3)
```

The important thing to understand about Lisp assignments is that they don't make copies of the list structure, they just assign references to the conses (if you're familiar with languages like C, it's like everything is a pointer to a `struct`).

Comment: after the first command we have a= (1 2 3), after next we have b= ((1 2 3) 2 3), am I right until now?

Comment: if we didnt thought as pointer, we say after the last command a=(1,5) and b=((1 2 3) 2 3) that was wrong. okey?

Comment: That's why you need to keep track of the specific conses that are involved in the relationships.

Comment: There's no copying going on when you set `(defvar b (cons a (cdr a))`. The cons that `b` refers to refers to some of the same cons cells that `a` points to.